# Python: Función para eliminar palabras de una frase no funciona (utilizo for loop)

Tags: python

```
def word_cleaner(txt, to_remove):
splitted = txt.split()
for i in splitted:
    for x in to_remove:
        if i == x:
            splitted.remove(x)
return " ".join(splitted)

ignore_self_words = ["i", "you", "he", "she", "us", "they"]
print(word_cleaner("hi there how are you you you you you", ignore_self_words))
```

Tengo la función "word_cleaner", para eliminar los pronombres de un texto, y si utilizo un texto como "hi there you" va a eliminar "you" con éxito, sin embargo un problema aparece cuando repito la palabra, y no encuentro ningún error en el codigo, alguien tiene una idea?

Comment: te complicas mucho, basta usar el operador `in` y si quieres una expresión generadora, así `return " ".join(x for x in txt.split() if not x in ignore_self_words)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: No puedes modificar un arreglo/secuencia/etc mientras lo recorres.

Solución: En lugar de eliminar, crea una nueva lista con las palabras válidas:

```
def word_cleaner(txt, to_remove):
    filtered = []
    for palabra in txt.split():
        if palabra not in to_remove:
            filtered.append(palabra)

    return " ".join(filtered)

ignore_self_words = ["i", "you", "he", "she", "us", "they"]
print(word_cleaner("hi there how are you you you you you", ignore_self_words))
```

produce:

```
hi there how are

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Recomendación: usa nombre significativos para las variables. El nombre "i" sugiere un entero usado para contar, cuando en realidad lo que tienes es una "palabra". Nombres significativos facilitan el razonar sobre el código.

**versión corta**

Lo mismo, pero expresado en forma concisa:

```
def word_cleaner(txt, to_remove):
    return " ".join([palabra for palabra in txt.split() if palabra not in to_remove])
```

Comment: Nota: El op podría no entender como funciona, pero para ahorrar velocidad y memoria, se puede evitar la creación de una lista intermedia quitando los corchetes. Esto hace que el objeto devuelto por la comprensión sea un generador (el cual NO almacena todos los datos en si mismo), el cual será luego recorrido por el join.

Comment: Gracias, a parte ahora aprendí a usar correctamente la comprensión de lista, gracias!

Comment: @DanteS. No siempre puedes usar generadores en lugar de comprensión de listas. Eso confunde a los novatos; mejor limitarse a usar comprensión. Si no, tendrás que entrar a explicar por que `len([x for x in "abc"])` funciona mientras que `len(x for x in "abc")` falla.

Comment: Si, eso es verdad. Por eso dejé la nota y dije que quizá el op no entendería. No está dirigido al OP ni para cambiar la respuesta.

Comment: De cualquier modo, `len(comprension de lista)` me parece un mal uso, para mi es mejor usar `sum(1 for <variable> in <iterable o iterador> if(<expresion>))` para saber la cantidad de items de una comprensión. Evitas de ese modo la lista intermedia.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es básicamente que `list.remove(item)` solo elimina el primer *item* que encuentre, si hay varios no lo hará. En tu caso si hay multiples *you* solo eliminará 1. Para eliminar todos puedes emplear un `ciclo-while`

Y lo mejor sería iterar sobre las palabras que deseas eliminar y no sobre cada una del texto objetivo para así evitar modificar la lista sobre la que iteras como advierte @CandidMoe .

siendo el código solución para la función:

```py
def word_cleaner(txt, to_remove):
    splitted = txt.split()
    for remove in to_remove:
        while remove in splitted:
            splitted.remove(remove)
    return ' '.join(splitted)
```

Comment: Anotado, muchisimas gracias.
PD: Sabes por qué exactamente es que elimina solo el primer item teniendo en cuenta que es un bucle for??

Comment: @Neo Me he equivocado afirmando eso, el error está en modificar la lista en la que iteras dentro de ciclo. Si haces lo mismo con una copia funciona normal.